# that claim and two slices of bread will get you a bologna sandwich -- what does this mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Source: [Absolute FreeBSD: The Complete Guide to FreeBSD, 2nd Edition by Michael W. Lucas (2008)](https://www.nostarch.com/abs_bsd2.htm)

Example:

> Tapes tend to stretch, especially after they’re used the first time. (I know
>   perfectly well that modern tape vendors all claim that they prestretch their
>   tapes, or that their tapes cannot be stretched, **but that claim and two slices of bread will get you a bologna sandwich**.) Retensioning a tape is simply running the tape completely through, both forwards and back, with the command *mt retension*.

What do you think he's trying to say there? Does this have something to do with the expression *baloney* which means nonsense talk?

Comment: In short, yes. He's stating that their claim is baloney.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's means the claim is [*baloney*](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Phoney%20Baloney), i.e. wrong in some form, because a bologna sandwich is commonly and willfully mispronounced as baloney sandwich.